# How do I quickly replace all transparent pixels with background color?

Tags: gimp, transparency, background, background-removal, krita

Some of my software tools generate images with transparent backgrounds. Using Krita, how can I quickly replace transparency with a background color?

**Notes:**

- Of course it would be easiest if the image was generated correctly. This is not possible right now.
- With GIMP I used the following workflow, but the equivalent steps don't work in Krita:

  1. Open image
  2. Select "Flatten image" (replaces transparency with default background color)
  3. Save image

Comment: my current workaround is to open the PNG and save as JPEG :D

Answer (score 2):

I would put a layer below the transparent object with the color I need and flatten it.

The additional steps would be to create the background layer and paint it.

Keep a copy of your original assets.

Answer (score 0):

In Gimp, for a single layer (so without flattening the image)

- Start the bucket-fill tool
- Set to `Behind` mode
- Set to `BG color fill` (or use Alt-click in next)
- Bucket fill the whole layer (without using a selection)

This will "fill the holes" exactly as needed (especially the semi-transparent pixels on the edges).